# Automatic width of textbox inside a FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

Inside a FlowLayoutPanel I have a label and a textbox sibe by side. When I change the width of the FlowLayoutPanel I also want the textbox width to change. Is this possible?

The controls are placed like this:

[ FLOWLAYOUTPANEL [LABEL][TEXTBOX] ]

EDIT: Based on Jay Stratemeyer and Hans Passant code and suggestion, I was able to have a label and a text box that resizes its width and wraps automatically. Here is the code:

```
    Private Sub FlowLayoutPanel1_Resize(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles FlowLayoutPanel1.Resize
        Dim new_width As Integer = FlowLayoutPanel1.ClientSize.Width - LabelControl1.Width - LabelControl1.Margin.Left - LabelControl1.Margin.Right - TextBox1.Margin.Left - TextBox1.Margin.Right

        If new_width > Me.TextBox1.MinimumSize.Width Then
            Me.TextBox1.Width = new_width
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Use the FlowLayoutPanel's Resize event.

Comment: Perhaps by embedding `TableLayoutPanel` inside `FlowLayoutPanel`, with the label and textbox inside the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load +=new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
    }

    public int MyFlowPanelOriginalSize { get; set; }
    public int MyFlowPanelNewSize { get; set; }
    public int DifferenceInSizeOfPanel { get; set; }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyFlowPanelOriginalSize = MyFlowPanel.Width;
        MyFlowPanel.Resize += new EventHandler(MyFlowPanel_Resize);
        DifferenceInSizeOfPanel = 0;
    }



    void MyFlowPanel_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyFlowPanelNewSize = MyFlowPanel.Width;
        DifferenceInSizeOfPanel = MyFlowPanelNewSize - MyFlowPanelOriginalSize;
        var TextBoxDifference = MyTextBox.Width + DifferenceInSizeOfPanel;
        MyTextBox.Width = TextBoxDifference;
        MyFlowPanelOriginalSize = MyFlowPanel.Width;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Jay, your code pointed me to the right direction and a little simpler solution. See my edit above.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and this is the default behavior of TableLayoutPanel, columns are set at 50% of the parent.

You can set your label column to fixed size (or Auto - to be based on the label text) and your textbox to a 100%. This way any resizing of the TableLayoutPanel will trigger a resize of your TextBox, and nothing else.

[image]

Comment: I am using the FlowLayoutPanle, not the TableLayoutPanel because I want the label and textbox controls to wrap in case they do not fit together on the same line.

Comment: @YiannisMpourkelis: How do you expect the resize to work? It's usually either fit to width, or wrap line behavior. Because by making it fit to width, you are essentially saying "I need any width from 0 to infinity". There is no way it can wrap lines this way (or at least not by default, you need to specify exactly how you see it working, may be possible with combination of min/max width). Please update your question and provide corner cases.

Comment: The textbox control (and other controls) has a MinimumSize property which is taken into account when the control is anchored inside a container